# How to store a standing table in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a World Cup prediction website which is written using the `Django` framework. Every time a user requests to see the standing table of a particular contest, the standing_stable view looks up all of the users associated with that contest, then loads up all of the associated games as well as users' predictions, then in a for loop compares the predicted result with the actual result and assigns scores based on a rule system. In my experience, when I have more than 10 users signed up in a contest that has at least 30 games or more, the standing_table view gets really slow and it takes more than 5-10 seconds to load the table.

I understand that the way I do this is not efficient, and I'd rather do the math once and for all after each game has ended and the users can be referred to those pre-built standing tables. I don't know, however, how to store such table as a `Django` model.

Here's my `show_standing` view

```
@login_required
def show_standing(request, contest):
    contest = request.user.contests.filter(name=contest).all()[0]
    users = contest.users.all()
    rows = []

    for user in users:
        exact_groupstage = utils.get_correct_predictions(user, contest, 'exact', 'groupstage')
        goal_difference_groupstage = utils.get_correct_predictions(user, contest, 'goal-difference', 'groupstage')
        winner_only_groupstage = utils.get_correct_predictions(user, contest, 'winner-only', 'groupstage')

        exact_playoffs = utils.get_correct_predictions(user, contest, 'exact', 'playoffs')
        goal_difference_playoffs = utils.get_correct_predictions(user, contest, 'goal-difference', 'playoffs')
        winner_only_playoffs = utils.get_correct_predictions(user, contest, 'winner-only', 'playoffs')

        row = []
        row.append(user)
        row.append(exact_groupstage + exact_playoffs)
        row.append(goal_difference_groupstage + goal_difference_playoffs)
        row.append(winner_only_groupstage + winner_only_playoffs)
        row.append(exact_groupstage*3 + goal_difference_groupstage*2 + winner_only_groupstage*1 +
                   exact_playoffs*6 + goal_difference_playoffs*4 + winner_only_playoffs*2)
        rows.append(row)

    rows = sorted(rows, key=lambda x:x[4], reverse=True)
    data = {'rows': rows,
            'contest': contest.name}

    return render(request, 'standing.html', data)
```

Here's how `get_correct_predictions` looks like:

```
def get_correct_predictions(user, contest, kind, round):
    bets = user.bets.filter(contest=contest)
    # games = Game.objects.all()

    num_exact_predictions = 0
    num_goal_dif_predictions = 0
    num_winner_only_predictions = 0

    for bet in bets:
        game = bet.game

        if not is_played(game):
            continue
        if round == 'groupstage':
            if game.isplayoff:
                continue
        elif round == 'playoffs':
            if not game.isplayoff:
                continue
        else:
            raise Exception('Round can only be "groupstage" or "playoffs"')

        home_predicted = bet.home_score
        away_predicted = bet.away_score
        home_actual = game.home_score
        away_actual = game.away_score

        # exact result predicted
        if (home_predicted == home_actual) and (away_predicted == away_actual):
            num_exact_predictions += 1
        # only goal difference predicted
        elif (home_predicted - away_predicted) == (home_actual - away_actual):
            num_goal_dif_predictions += 1
        # only winner predicted
        elif (home_predicted - away_predicted) * (home_actual - away_actual) > 0:
            num_winner_only_predictions += 1

    if kind == 'exact':
        return num_exact_predictions
    elif kind == 'goal-difference':
        return num_goal_dif_predictions
    elif (kind == 'winner-only'):
        return num_winner_only_predictions
```

Edit 1: Here are my models:

```
class Contest(models.Model):
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='contests')

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=3)

class Game(models.Model):
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, related_name='games')
    home = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='%(class)s_home')
    away = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='%(class)s_away')
    home_score = models.IntegerField()
    away_score = models.IntegerField()
    isplayoff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    scheduled_datetime = models.DateTimeField()

class Bet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='bets')
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, related_name='bets')
    contest = models.ForeignKey(Contest, related_name='bets')
    home_score = models.IntegerField()
    away_score = models.IntegerField()
```

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: How are your current models defined?

Comment: @blhsing I just edited the question.